# Trace/BPT Trap with Rails via browser but not console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've written a Rails application that uses the Subversion Ruby bindings. I've written adapters classes to adapt them to an interface of my liking.

After upgrading my project to Rails 3 and recompiling the SVN bindings for Ruby 1.9.2, I can go to the debug console and run require 'svn/core/ext' with no problems, as before. However, I get Trace/BPT trap when my adapter (which also runs require 'svn/ext/core') is included.

So in summary, I get Trace/BPT trap when running my appliation using Webrick and connection via browser, but I do not ge the error via the console.

Any ideas why or how I can debug this? The logs show nothing at all.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue in the past using a PDFLib library - where it didn't work in Webrick - but it did work in the console. Also after a Ruby upgrade.

I installed POW ([http://pow.cx/](http://pow.cx)) and, I no longer get the Trace/BPT error.

So I would try use a different web server - and for my OS X machine, POW was the least painful one to install.

Comment: +1 Not much in the way of a solution, but what a fantastic workaround! :) That's a great server!

Comment: +1 I had the same problem with *Ruby 2.0.0p0*, *Rails 4.0.0.rc1* and *Webrick*. Installing *thin* solved my problem.